# How to use Firebird with Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, firebird, activerecord-fb-adapter

I am trying to update my rails application from version 4.1.6 to 4.2.0. 
Almost all are going well, except that I have two database connections (one is the default Postgres and other is used for reading data from another legacy application). The second uses Firebird (fb) adapter.
In Rails 4.2 I cannot do anything with this second (fb) database. All commands result in this error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `compile' for #

To reproduce the case, I created a new application from scratch using adapter 'fb' and a simple model called Foo with two string columns. After I called from rails console the command `Foo.count`
the result is the same.

[Here is the full call stack for the problem](https://gist.github.com/douglaslise/fbe5e82c2aad0e9d8abb)

I tried to investigate the sources but I could not determine where is the problem. I think it has due to some changes/optimizations in activerecord in version 4.2 but I don't know exactly.

Thanks in advance by any help.

Comment: [According to Brent Rowland](https://twitter.com/brentrowland/status/551876589885992961) it is because the adapter is not yet compatible with 4.2 (ruby apparently doesn't provide binary compatibility)

Comment: OK, I downgraded my app to still using Rails 4.1. Thanks @MarkRotteveel.

Comment: time to revisit this, as [4.2 support has been available since almost a month ago](https://github.com/rowland/activerecord-fb-adapter/issues/47)

Comment: Thanks @Mario by the tip. I did see the pull request closed but I didn't see the gem version updated (what occured one day after the issue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gem `activerecord-fb-adapter` version `1.0.1` has now support for rails `~>4.2`, according this [*closed issue*](https://github.com/rowland/activerecord-fb-adapter/issues/47#event-274716028).